# Auto populate rows in smartsheet from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, smartsheet-api

Is it possible to use Smartsheet's API to auto-populate data from SQL Server?

I'd like to extract data from SQL Server to Smartsheet. I have 5 columns ITEMID, Name, Type, Cost, Location.

If I enter an `Itemid`, the code should look in the database table and if `Itemid` is present, then the code should auto-populate the rest of the columns.

Can I do this with API? C# or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible through the [Smartsheet API](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/) using [webhooks](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#webhooks).

You can [create a webhook](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#creating-a-webhook) that notifies your code whenever a sheet changes.

When your code receives those notifications, you can then grab that `Itemid` from the [row](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-row),
 so that you can query your database.

If there is a match in your db, then [update the row](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#update-rows) with the values returned in your db query.